# best spring terminals for AWG30 wires

Tags: wire-terminals

which of these spring terminals suits better AWG30 wires?

I've found 3 types:

1. [PCB Mount type (rated for 26 to 20AWG)](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8074)
2. [Wago/lever type (rated for AWG28-12)](http://www.ebay.com/itm/10PCS-SPRING-LEVER-TERMINAL-BLOCK-ELECTRIC-CABLE-WIRE-CONNECTOR-2-WAY-LM/332087793406)
3. [CH-3 type (i've found no rating for these)](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/201132985009)
4. other solderless terminals you suggest?

Most of them are signal wires only. A few of them will drive some current  within the USB specs (<500mA).
The installation spot won't vibrate much (it's a box over my desktop).
I am mostly interested to avoid damaging the wires due to excessive pressure.

Comment: The problem will be finding a terminal block that will close far enough to make good contact with #30 wire - the first two are not specified to work with #30.

Comment: Is there any reason you need to use 30AWG?

Comment: I haven't done this with 30AWG, but I have done it with 28AWG. Use ferrules on the wires prior to connecting to the terminal strip. Instead of pushing the bare wire into the strip, you push the ferrule into the strip. The ferrules crimp onto the stripped end of the wire with an inexpensive crimping tool.

Comment: #3 won't work; those cheap clips aren't very tight, even 24awg slips out of mine. speaker terminals are your best bet for connecting thin bare wire.

Comment: Assuming you're using stranded wire, one option for using #1 and #2 is to bend the end of the wire over before inserting it, so that there are 2x diameter. This effectively converts your AWG30 wire into AWG24 for the clamp. For personal use, I'd just try this.

Comment: Consider suitable crimp connectors and headers (many 2mm families will work well with 30 AWG stranded), or if it solid core wire, a wire wrap tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one with the strongest spring for best.  My guess is the one with the highest minimum size will be best.  This points to the 1st choice. In order to satisfy the AWG requirement, the wire end must be doubled and twisted or heavy hot solder dipped ends.

Jacket thickness helps with some strain relief.

If none like magnet wire, then you will want to use a wax string to tie wrap the bundle like dental floss and use twisted pairs for noise immunity with a ground wire.

Answer (score 1):

None of them are rated for AWG30, so you are just **asking for trouble**. Pressure may be too low or it may cut the wire.

Wurth [has some](http://katalog.we-online.de/em/datasheet/691412320007.pdf) that are actually rated for the wire size you have:

[image]

[image]

I would test them carefully in simulated or real use conditions. In most cases AWG30 is too fine for reliable field connections of individual wires. In high vibration environments AWG20 is about the limit, and even in more benign environments AWG24 or 28 would be much, much better.